# @Query with or, and

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data

In my db I have two types of users: test and production. I have the method to search them by id or order number. In db is column with boolean param isTest (true if user is from test enviroment and false for other). I have to make query in repository(spring data, jpa) with free params (id, oorderId and isTest) and I want to display only productions users. I made something lkie this (but doesn't work, I mean the search by orderId or id is ok but boolean property is not):

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

@Query(select u from User where u.orderId = ?1 or u.id = ?1 and isTest = false")
Page<User> searchUsers(Pageable pageable, String orderId, String id, boolean isTest);
```

}
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/operator-precedence.html), `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.  Therefore your current filter is evaluated as:

```
WHERE u.orderId = ?1 OR (u.id = ?1 AND isTest = false)
```

You should add explicit parentheses to force the precedence that suits your requirements:

```
WHERE (u.orderId = ?1 OR u.id = ?1) AND isTest = false
```

Comment: +1 it is good practice to always use parenthesis to clarify what is meant which makes it easier for when you start working in a team with someone else who has to understand your code.